# Word for reading without a pause

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for reading something *continuously without a pause*?

> He read the whole paragraph ...

Comment: By the way...it's not clear from question whether you mean "read aloud" or "ready to himself". It may not matter ... but then it might!

Comment: Good point, @MarkBeadles! I assumed the former, because he happened to ask about reading a _paragraph_.  Had he asked about something longer, though (like a _chapter_, or a _book_), I might have assumed otherwise, and suggested _in one sitting_, instead of _in one breath_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatically, you could say:

> He read the whole paragraph *without taking a breath*.

Or maybe:

> He read the whole paragraph *like an auctioneer*.

Comment: Instead of "read", I'd use "rattled off".

Comment: @Marthaª: I agree; that would further improve the prose.

Comment: Can we also *He read the whole paragraph in one breath*?

Comment: @Noah: Sure, that's another variation – I even mentioned that one in my [comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65394/word-for-reading-without-a-pause#comment124673_65394) above.

Answer (score 3):

"...**[through](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through%5B2%5D)**."

"...**[straight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straight%5B2%5D)**."

"...**straight through**." also works..

Comment: and you can "pile through" if you're trying to emphasize the intensity of effort

Answer (score 2):

You could well say "He **devoured** the book", which implies that it was compelling to such an extent, that the person read it without taking breaks. That being said, "devour" would sound odd used with a "paragraph", especially one read aloud. Since you didn't provide much context, I consider it to be one of the possibilities.

On reflection, "He read the whole paragraph **in a single breath**" might be the expression you've been looking for.